# Opening directory

Tags: java, directory, desktop

I have this little piece of code

```
File dir = new File("./brieven");
try {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir);
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it works fine on windows 7, but when I try it on windows 8 it gives a `Java.to.IOException` with the error message `The System couldn't find the file specified`

So my question is, what do I have to do to open the directory in windows 8 and windows 7

Edit:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("./brieven");

if (Files.exists(dir) && Files.isDirectory(dir)) {
    try {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir.toFile);
        }
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Now trying it with `toRealPath()` but the program stops working.

```
try {
    Path dir = Paths.get("./brieven").toRealPath();
    if (Files.exists(dir) && Files.isDirectory(dir) && Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir.toFile());
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit 3: Tried it on another laptop with windows 8, and it works fine

Comment: First, try and obtain a better diagnostic by using the new file API: `dir = Paths.get("./brieven"); Files.exists(dir); Files.isDirectory(dir);`

Comment: @fge changed it a bit (see edit) but `Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir);`  gives an error `the method open(file) is not applicable`

Comment: Use `dir.toFile()` to obtain a `File` from a `Path`

Comment: Does the `brieven` folder exist on your Windows 8 box? You are using a relative path, did you execute it from the wrong place? Try changing your code to `File dir = new File("C:\\");` and see if it works on both boxes.

Comment: @Duncan it is automatically made when the program runs

Comment: @LiamdeHaas Still worth trying to my ``C:\\`` test, I think. Could help rule out some things.

Comment: @fge change it, gives me the same error as before on win 8

Comment: @Duncan I misunderstood your suggestion. Tried it and it opens `C:` on both boxes

Comment: So it means the directory actually exists, eh? Can you see whether `Files.getPosixPermissions(dir).containsAll(EnumSet.of(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ, PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE))` returns true? (that is, provided _you_ are the onwer of the file)

Comment: @fge it says `the method getPosixPermissions is undefined for the type Files`

Comment: It should be `.getPosixFilePermissions`, sorry

Comment: @fge it gives an `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: OK, then try and see if `Files.isReadable()` and `Files.isExecutable()`; both must be true for you to be able to read the directory contents

Comment: @fge both return true

Comment: Uh, I'm running out of ideas there. Try and explore all attributes of the file... See [here](http://andreinc.net/2013/12/05/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-file-attributes/) for more info

Comment: @fge thanks for the effort, I was thinking maybe something with `getAbsolutePath()` or the `toAbsolutePath()` of Path?

Comment: On `Path`, you have `.toRealPath()`; try this and see what it gives. Note that it can throw an exception

Comment: @fge I have this `Path dir = Paths.get("./brieven").toRealPath();` and this `Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir.toFile());` and when I print `dir` to the console it gives the path. but when it comes to the opening the program stops working

Comment: @fge tried it on another laptop wit win 8 and it works like a charm. something wrong with the laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    Path dir = Paths.get("./brieven").toRealPath();
    if (Files.exists(dir) && Files.isDirectory(dir) && Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir.toFile());
    }
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```